# Why grub stuck at boot using UEFI, and with VGA unplugged?

Tags: grub, headless, debian-jessie

I want to make a headless server using Debian 8 (Jessie) in an UEFI machine. After installation the machine boots only with a VGA plugged.

Comment: What makes you think it's GRUB? And if you try to boot the system headless, and then plug in a monitor after some time, what exactly does it show?

Comment: Because, it is the first thing after the setup screen. When I plug it back nothing is shown, the screen goes to stand-by mode.

Comment: I'm not at all sure you can conclude from that data that the problem is GRUB. Try unplugging the hard drive, remove the install CD, and booting headless, which should cause the firmware to display a "no operating system found" error, and tell us what the results of that are. Just trying to narrow down the issue here, and having some concrete data in order to properly diagnose the problem.

Comment: I  tested, after install rEFInd I can boot directly the partition. When the choose partition is grub: it stuck without VGA plugged.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) -- this way it is possible to boot my  linux partition directly, skipping grub, and works without the VGA plugged.

Now I have a headless server *de fato*.